# Grouped Bar chart - scaling problem

Tags: pgfplots, spacing, bar-chart

I am trying to plot bar charts for a publication with tikz, for the plots with 5 bars it works very well, as soon as I use more or less 5 the bars push into each other, or tikz creates multiple labels and pulls the bars apart. It seems to me that all charts have the same size and that's why there is a problem.

Here is the code from a chart that works:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
    xbar,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line       = none,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
    enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
    symbolic y coords = {Infizierte Bewohner:innen in Prozent, Zuzahlung PG2+, Zuzahlung PG1, Träger-Art, Einbettzimmer in Prozent},
    nodes near coords,
    legend style={at={(1.2,1)}}
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {    (2.33,Infizierte Bewohner:innen in Prozent)        
                        (20.53,Zuzahlung PG2+)
                                        (20.33,Zuzahlung PG1)  
                                        (14.1,Träger-Art) 
                                        (19.3,Einbettzimmer in Prozent)};
  
  \addplot coordinates {    (35.38,Infizierte Bewohner:innen in Prozent)         
                        (12.63,Zuzahlung PG2+) 
                                    (12.98,Zuzahlung PG1)   
                                    (19.63,Träger-Art)      
                                    (14.01,Einbettzimmer in Prozent)};

\legend{Low/Non-Profit, High/For Profit}

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: This plot works properly]

And here from the one with 5+ bars:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
    xbar,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line       = none,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
  enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
  enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
     symbolic y coords = {Infizierte Mitarbeiter:innen in Prozent, Infizierte Bewohner:innen in Prozent, Fachkraftquote, Mitarbeiter:innenquote, Zuzahlung PG2+, Zuzahlung PG1, Träger-Art, Anzahl an Betten},
    nodes near coords,
    legend style={at={(1.2,1.2)}}
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {    (2.78,Infizierte Mitarbeiter:innen in Prozent)
                        (2.71,Infizierte Bewohner:innen in Prozent)        
                        (2.11,Fachkraftquote)
                        (2.16,Mitarbeiter:innenquote)
                        (1.91,Zuzahlung PG2+)
                                        (1.85,Zuzahlung PG1)  
                                        (2.34,Träger-Art) 
                                        (1.54,Anzahl an Betten)     
                                        };
  
  \addplot coordinates {    (2.01,Infizierte Mitarbeiter:innen in Prozent)         
                        (2.07,Infizierte Bewohner:innen in Prozent)
                        (2.01,Fachkraftquote)
                        (1.83,Mitarbeiter:innenquote)
                        (2.44,Zuzahlung PG2+) 
                                    (2.29,Zuzahlung PG1)   
                                    (1.91,Träger-Art)  
                                    (2.81,Anzahl an Betten)     
                                    };

\legend{Low, High}

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
 
 \caption{Signifikante Unterschiede bei der Anzahl der Ausbrüche. Quelle: Eigene Darstellung.}
\label{fig:ausbruch}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Here, the labels are wrong and the plots are mixed up.]

And the plot with only 2 bars:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
    xbar,
   y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line       = none,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
 enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
  enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
    symbolic y coords = {Fachkraftquote, Anzahl der Betten},
    nodes near coords,
    legend style={at={(1.4,1)}}
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {     (37.94,Fachkraftquote)   
                                    (32.23,Anzahl der Betten)   
                                        };
  
  \addplot coordinates {    (32.83,Fachkraftquote) 
                                    (33.44,Anzahl der Betten)   
                                    };

\legend{Low, High}

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\caption{Signifikante Unterschiede in der Dauer der Ausbrüche (mindestens ein Tag) gruppiert nach UV.Quelle: Eigene Darstellung.}
\label{fig:dauer0}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Here, too, the labels are wrong, and the bars are too far apart.]

Can someone help me? The search function at Stackoverflow and Reddit, as well as the documentation of tikz didn't help me - maybe because I don't really understand the problem yet (I started working with latex only 2 weeks ago).

And maybe an additional question: is it possible to add confidence intervals in my plots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set `ytick=data`. You are better to see the enlarge limit effect when there are axis lines drawn. Enlarge limit will make the two bars plot drawn in the proper distance. Also you axis height is too short for more than 5 bars. I adjust the y tick label style in the first plot to allow have multiple lines in the y tick label. I also tweak the legend style a little bit to have two columns legend. I set the first plot width to fit page layout. You need to adjust the width according to your page layout. That's why you should provide a minimum work example. Because my setting only good for this particular case. You didn't include which document class you are using. I will use `article` class as example. Following is a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
    xbar,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line = none,
    height=13cm,
    width=14cm,
    tickwidth = 0pt,
    ytick = data,
    symbolic y coords = {Infizierte Mitarbeiter:innen in Prozent, Infizierte Bewohner:innen in Prozent, Fachkraftquote, Mitarbeiter: innenquote, Zuzahlung PG2+, Zuzahlung PG1, Träger-Art, Anzahl an Betten},
    yticklabel style={align=right,text width=3cm},
    nodes near coords,
    legend style = {at={(1,1.05)}},
    legend columns = 2,
  ]
\addplot coordinates {
(2.78,Infizierte Mitarbeiter:innen in Prozent)
(2.71,Infizierte Bewohner:innen in Prozent)        
(2.11,Fachkraftquote)
(2.16,Mitarbeiter: innenquote)
(1.91,Zuzahlung PG2+)
(1.85,Zuzahlung PG1)  
(2.34,Träger-Art) 
(1.54,Anzahl an Betten)
};
  
\addplot coordinates {
(2.01,Infizierte Mitarbeiter:innen in Prozent)(2.07,Infizierte Bewohner:innen in Prozent)
(2.01,Fachkraftquote)
(1.83,Mitarbeiter: innenquote)
(2.44,Zuzahlung PG2+) 
(2.29,Zuzahlung PG1)   
(1.91,Träger-Art)  
(2.81,Anzahl an Betten)     
};

\legend{Low, High}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\caption{Signifikante Unterschiede bei der Anzahl der Ausbrüche. Quelle: Eigene Darstellung.}
\label{fig:ausbruch}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    xbar,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line = none,
    tickwidth = 0pt,
    symbolic y coords = {Fachkraftquote, Anzahl der Betten},
    ytick = data,
    nodes near coords,
    enlarge y limits = 1,
    enlarge x limits = 0.5,
    legend style={at={(1,1)}},
    legend columns=2,
]
\addplot coordinates {
(37.94,Fachkraftquote) (32.23,Anzahl der Betten)
};
\addplot coordinates {
(32.83,Fachkraftquote) (33.44,Anzahl der Betten)
};
\legend{Low, High}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Signifikante Unterschiede in der Dauer der Ausbrüche (mindestens ein Tag) gruppiert nach UV.Quelle: Eigene Darstellung.}
\label{fig:dauer0}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This has helped me a lot! Yes, I use Article as a style. I misinterpreted the "data" command, but thanks to your execution I understand it now! 

Thanks again!